# BreadCrumb URL in Wordpress VertiMagazine Theme

Tags: wordpress, seo, breadcrumbs

How can i make URLs of blogpost as breadcrumb like this

> Home>Facebook Status>Love Status

I have tried all in seo plugins and seo by yoast but still there is no option for that.
Please give me brief answer how should i modify the theme to make my url appears in breadcrumbs in google search.
here is url http://love-status.com

Comment: I dont understand you question properly - can you explain a little more please?

Comment: i want to know if there's a seperate plugin to make urls appear like breadcrumbs as shown in example.

Comment: you want the URL to display breadcrumbs? or you want to put breadcrumbs on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly Implement Breadcrumbs to your blog by using  WordPress SEO by Yoast plugin and bit of php code . Visit the following link for more detail -> https://managewp.com/breadcrumbs-wordpress-seo-by-yoast